# Comment pop up disappears and a "confirm" button appears instead when using facebook like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress, facebook-like

I'm trying to include a facebook like button in my wordpress blog with the correspondent opengraph tags to show an image, description, etc. While I was testing it (liking and unliking a lot to check results), after clicking the like button, the comment pop up blinked and then out of the blue a "confirm" link appeared. This is so annoying.

I've later researched the issue (after banging my head for a big big while) just to find out it seems to be part of a fb policy applied to suspicious sites to prevent spam. Is there any way to fix this?  What can I do?  This is really a bad thing since this way of having to confirm will draw back a lot of people from "liking" items in my page. :( is there any solution?

Answer (score 8):

This protection automatically goes away once users start liking [and confirming] the page normally. If it was triggered accidentally it's most likely because you were liking/unliking the page multiple times and/or it was reported as spam by friends of someone liking the page repeatedly. There's no way to have it overridden but it should go away automatically

Comment: Thank you so much.  This cost me a day trying to track down.

Comment: My confirm pop up is blank... why?