# Facebook Like without Confirm?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I think I have the same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218858/comment-pop-up-disappears-and-a-confirm-button-appears-instead-when-using-faceb), but can't quite get enough out of the answers over there.

I'm using a Like button (in an iframe on a Static XFBML page) to allow users to Like a YouTube video, with the intention that since the user clicks Like it shares it to their Wall.

What happens is that they click Like, it says "You like this", but nothing is posted, and then after a random short interval the Like button is replaced by a Confirm hyperlink.

What I really want is no "Confirm" stage because a) it's clunky and b) the user has probably left the page by then. I know there's at least one app that does it... Is this behaviour possible for me to code, and if so, how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook like button is asking to confirm the action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083996/facebook-like-button-is-asking-to-confirm-the-action)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

this is a feature of the like button, so as to avoid spamming website that cheat user on the like buttons.  The "confirm" feature will be turn on for suspicious site.  When your site is well received and get positive feedback, the "confirm" feature will be removed automatically.

Comment: This is in an established site with a few hundred fans and the videos in question have already been liked by some fans before we put up this new code. So, given that, does anyone anyone know how long it will take to go away?

Comment: I think facebook does not just count the no. of like.... it has a set of rules to determine suspicious sites.  For example, if you site get 100,000 users accessing it and 100,000 of them clicked the same like button, this is very suspicious.

For the exact rules, there won't be anyone that can tell you... as Facebook will never disclose that.

Comment: Well, I have done nothing like that! I understand why they don't tell you the exact rules - I was hoping maybe someone would say "Oh for my site it took a week, or 3 more likes" or something like that to give me hope!

Comment: has it gone away after these days?

Answer (score -3):

In your case it's because you implemented it using an `<iframe>` - I've tried it before and the `<iframe>` is the cause.

Comment: it happens on an "html5" implementation as well.

Comment: Do you have a source for that?