# Confirm Link Appearing after Clicking Like Button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I just switched to a new host, changed all the information on my Facebook application settings page, and added the Open Graph namespace URL to my HTML element.  What's the deal?  On my old domain it was working and both accounts are subdomains. *The difference between mine and other complaints of similar issues* is that **likes are not going through** for me.  Please help.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Like without Confirm?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7405485/facebook-like-without-confirm)

Comment: I saw the other similar articles but as you can see on my edited post I had forgot to mention there are no likes are registering (they go away after refresh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Facebook's anti-spam measure. It will go away once people have started like-ing it.

See [Facebook Like without Confirm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405485/facebook-like-without-confirm)

Comment: See by my edited post I had forgot to mention there are no likes are registering (they go away after refresh).

Comment: I'll go ahead and give it to you although I don't think I'll ever know exactly why it did that for that domain specifically.  I'm sure it was because it was a free host and those tend to be on many domains' blacklists.

Answer (score 1):

This is Facebook's anti-spam measure and It will go away once people have started like-ing it.

One note to people seeing this issue. Majority of the time when you see this and you KNOW you're not phishing for likes, it's mostly likely because your **QA team** has **liked and unliked content multiple times** and short amount of time. This behavior sets off facebook's spam flags and thus adds the confirm button.

Hope that helps.