# Facebook Like Button popup dialog closing immediately after clicking

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbml

I am simply trying to test a bit of like functionality on a test page and am getting unexpected behavior. When I click the like button the dialog(the one where you can add text and post to your wall) pops up for about half a second before closing by itself. The like button itself turns into a link that says "confirm". I really have the bare bones here and am not sure what could be going wrong. I'm using FBML. Here is the complete code for my test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Facebook Like Test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>
         window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: 'myid',
                status: true, // check login status
                cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        } (document));

    </script>

    <h1>Facebook Like Testing</h1>
    <div>
        <fb:like href = "http://www.example.com?id=1"></fb:like>
    </div>
    <div>
        <fb:like href = "http://www.example.com?id=2"></fb:like>
    </div>
    <div>
        <fb:like href = "http://www.example.com?id=3"></fb:like>
    </div>
    <div>
        <fb:like href = "http://www.example.com?id=4"></fb:like>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

I simply appended an arbitrary as a query string to make the hrefs unique. What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I'm going to answer my own question because I found out the issue and would like the answer to be there for anyone else who gets this error.

As it turns out the problem was not with my code but with the href I was specifying. I found the answer
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405485/facebook-like-without-confirm) . It has to do with the site I was implementing this on not being known well enough or flagged as "suspicious".

Answer (score 1):

How about the console output? Any errors or something?

I guess, you should check domain settings for your app and local environment. Your example works perfectly for me.

Last thing which pops in to my mind is, if you're using Chrome, it sometimes blocks crossdomain js request, so I would look for that also.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. No I am getting no errors in my output. My app config has mydomain.com under "App Domains". I've even tried using the code generated by FB and I'm still having this problem. I'm puzzled to say the least.

Comment: Well are you directly accessing the url "mydomain.com" while testing your script? Because your app needs to be run directly from domain you've set in facebook's app setting. You can always use hosts file for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turns out, the problem is that I had the cookies disabled on chrome. Once I enabled them, it started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

If the test page you mention is on a staging server or is using a URL other than the site that the Like is actually for, it will cause the Like dialogue to close because of the domain matching check that is performed when a user attempts to like the page.

I have found in the past that performing the testing on a hidden page on the live server will give you the result you're looking for.

If you have made changes on the page since you first tested the Like button, be sure to use the Facebook Developers Debug Tool on the page to re-build the cached page that Facebook has stored.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Scrutinize your open-graph declarations of the URL your share:
a simple mistake missing domain name on og:image declaration will cause the sharing-dialog popup to close without any console or error message.
(just do a control-u to view the source of the HTML page, look at your header-area for og:image, og:url etc.)